# How to test component that use URL api using Jest in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs, angular2-services

I am have a case where my code is using the URL api, created as such:

```
 let url = new URL('...');
 url.searchParams.set('action', action);
```

How ever while writing unit test it fails and the Error is:

```
 TypeError: Invalid URL: service
```

*So far what i tried:*

```
let mockUrl:URL;
describe('MyService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockUrl = new URL(dummyUrl);
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [{provide:URL, useValue:mockUrl}]
    });
  });
```

Error remains the same

Comment: Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60820403/jest-testing-with-url-object

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not the URL object that you need to provide in the providers array, basically Jest understand URL by default, they issue is URL object receives invalid URL thus it throws *TypeError: Invalid URL*

```
let url = new URL(undefined); //or invalid Url
```